# How should I escape the quotes in an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

Following is my code where I am trying to run the load query, but it's not running because of mismanaged quotes in the `$qry` string. Please explain how I can correct the query so that it can execute.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$list=array();
//array_push($list,"304_updated_24may.csv");
array_push($list,"filename1.csv");
array_push($list,"filename2.csv");
array_push($list,"filename3.csv");
array_push($list,"filename4.csv");

try
{
    foreach($list as $array)
    {
        echo 'hi';
        $qry='LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '.$array.' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '/"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS';
        print($qry);
        print($qry);
        $sqlvar= mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or printf("Errormessage2: %s\n", $mysqli->error);

    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Panic is rigth above. I did a similar solution. The following is what i did. I used pdo->quote() to escape my quotations. Should get around your problem.

```
        $databasehost = "your database host"; 
    $databasename = "your database name"; 
    $databasetable = "table name"; 
    $databaseusername = "database username"; 
    $databasepassword = "database password"; 
    $fieldseparator = ","; 
    $lineseparator = "\r\n";
    $enclosedby = '\"'; // notice that we escape the double quotation mark
    $csvfile = "your_csv_file_name.csv"; // this is your $list of csv files... replace as $list = array(); and array_push into list.

    // check to see if you have the file in the first place
    if(!file_exists( $csvfile )) {
        die( "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path." );
    }

    try {
            $pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
                $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
                array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                )
            );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
    }

    // Load your file into the database table, notice the quote() function, protects you from dangerous quotes 
    $qry = $pdo->exec( "
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " . $pdo->quote( $csvfile ) . " INTO TABLE $databasetable FIELDS TERMINATED BY " . $pdo->quote( $fieldseparator ) . 
        " OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY " . $pdo->quote( $enclosedby ) . 
        " LINES TERMINATED BY " . $pdo->quote( $lineseparator ) );
```